# How can i get the un-validated data in django rest dramework 3

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django rest framework 3 says to use something like this

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save(user=request.user)  # Include the user when saving.
```

Now my problem is that i want to fix the data before this step because it is in differnet format as required by serializer.

So data is in validated and i can't reach this step.

I want to fix the data before it reaches this stage.

Is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.data contains raw/un-validated data. Can be rewritten as

```
 def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # incoming data validation goes here
        raw_data = request.data
        fixed_data = process_data_function(raw_data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=fixed_data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(user=request.user)  # Include the user when saving.
```

Comment: thanks for that , so request.data will be json or python dict. i want to edit  some properties . do i need to use josn.loads

Comment: `request.data` will always be a Python dictionary (similar to `request.POST` provided by Django).